# how to stop postback when calling timer control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have to show date and timer on my project . and i am using the code :

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sc2" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateTimer" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="UpdateTimer" runat="server"  OnTick="UpdateTimer_Tick" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="DateStampLabel"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

but when i run on the local . it postback every seconds  and after that timer stops . any idea to correct the code.

C# Code:

```
protected void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateStampLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Not sure what is the problem, isn't that the purpose that page postback per second? Or the label is not updating?

Comment: if page is postback every seconds then i cant fill the details on the same page as it is getting refresh and control is going to VS (i have a break point) and then label stops to works .

Comment: So are you saying that the page is refreshing the page while the Timer postback? If yes, that must be something wrong with your updatepanel

Comment: How is your code exactly? could you update them in the question?

Comment: Code is same as :

Comment: So where is the 'details on the same page' you mentioned?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whats wrong with your code, but try this below code if it can help you.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>
     <h3 class="bp-header__title">Time :         <font color="red" size="4px"><asp:Label ID="lbl_Time" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Bold="false" Font-Names="Digital-7 Mono"></asp:Label></font></h3><br />
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the sample works by the following code

.aspx:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form id="frm" runat="server">


    <asp:ScriptManager ID="sc2" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateTimer" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="UpdateTimer" runat="server"  OnTick="UpdateTimer_Tick" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="DateStampLabel"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateStampLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

If the page is refreshing during postback, that may be because some javascript error on your page, sometime javascript exception in other section will break the .NET async postback. If your label is not updating, you may want to check if there are any `Response.Write`, `Response.Filter`, `Server.xxx` in your `Page_Load`/`Tick` event, since the ajax is returning anything you wrote to response, you may encountered `The message received from the server could not be parsed.` message.