# How can I disable the automatic postback on an aspx page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm developing a solution on visual studio and my view is a .aspx file with a .aspx.cs controller (C#), but on excecution the page refreshes automatilcally every 60 seconds and I would like to extended infinitely or at least longer than the 60s.

Please if the answer is already out there and I skipped it, explain the problem in the comments.

Thank you for reading and thank you in advance if you can help me.

I've already done the following commands on my code:
On the html:
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300" />
On the code behind:
Session.Timeout = 300;

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a couple of timers on the aspx page and they weren't set so the default time is 60 sec and everytime the tic they do a postback on default so look in your code if there's any timer and check if it is really necessary.
If you really need the timer just put it inside of an Update panel section just as shown here:
[how to stop postback when calling timer control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39324886/how-to-stop-postback-when-calling-timer-control)